# How to get GUI on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, user-interface

I have installed a Evaluation 180 days version of SQL Server 2012 from the [official website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29066) of Microsoft, on a Windows Server 2012 R2 (with gui). At the end of the installation in the Installation center, everything passed and succedeed but when I quit the program, I don't have any way to execute SQL Server from a graphical interface. I can see MS instances created, services running but how can I get a GUI to work with SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the newer version of SQL Servers, the SQL Server Management Studio (the GUI) is a separate install and you will need to install it separately to the database engine installation (which is what you have done). You can download SSMS from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062. The page contains a lot of different download components, make sure you check the appropriate install and click download.

**ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe** if you want the 64bit installation of SQL Management Studio

**ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe** for the 32bit version.

Answer (score 1):

```
you Need to Install SSMS
SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is a tool to manage and administer SQL Server and SQL Database.

SSMS is offered free of charge by Microsoft.
```